# FDR Error fdrtool in R

Tags: sql, r

Iam using fdrtool for my pvalues but i have an error which is :

Error in if (max(x) > 1 | min(x) < 0) stop("input p-values must all be in the range 0 to 1!") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The p value are not less than 0,greater than 1.
 The range of p value are [1,0].  the code is :

```
   n=40000

 pval1<-vector(length=n)

 pval1[1:n]= pv1list[["Pvalue"]]

 fdr<-fdrtool(pval1,statistic="pvalue")
```

Comment: ITS A CSV FILE OF ID and Pvalue

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code without problem (although I can't reproduce it because I don't have the object "pvlist").

Since you're having a missing value error, my guess is that you're having problems reading the csv file into R. I recommend the "read.table" function since from my experience it usually reads in data from a csv file without errors:

```
pvlist<- read.table("c:/pvslit.csv", header=TRUE,
sep=",", row.names="id")
```

And now you want to check the number of rows and missingness:

```
nrow(pvlist) # is this what you expect?
nrow(na.omit(pvlist)) # how many non-missing rows are there?
```

Additionally you want to make sure that your "p-value" column is not a character or factor:

```
str(pvlist) # examining the structure of the dataframe
pvlist[,2] <- as.numeric(pvlist[,2]) # assuming the 2nd column is the pvalue
```

In short, you most likely have a problem with reading in the data or the class of the data in the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much , statsRus how can i send you my  csv file??

Comment: i have this error :   pvlist[,2] <- as.numeric(pvlist[,2])
Error in `[.data.frame`(pvlist, , 2) : undefined columns selected. and  my csv file is composite of (ID,Pvalue ) the iD is generated by Rstudio i just put label in csv file ID  ??

Comment: i used : pvlist[,1] <- as.numeric(pvlist[,1])    then fdrtool :                   fdr<-fdrtool(pvlist,statistic="pvalue") i have an error : Error in fdrtool(pvlist, statistic = "pvalue") : 
  input test statistics must be given as a vector!

Comment: Why not try `myp <- as.numeric(pvlist[,1])`?

Comment: oh i have same error :(   Error in if (max(x) > 1 | min(x) < 0) stop("input p-values must all be in the range 0 to 1!") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: please i would like send you the csv file   statsRus ?? coul

Comment: Sorry, I'm only here to help answering questions! :-)